# How to use prevent default event for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, return-value, preventdefault

I want to prevent send data to database when user use numbers in the username input for example. I used `event.prevent Default()` for that, but not working.(also `return false`) what should I do?

My code:

PHP:

```
if (!empty($shomare) && !empty($pass) && !empty($first) && !empty($last)) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'portal');
    $sql = " INSERT INTO students (shomare,pass,first,last,major,birth) VALUES ('$shomare','$hashpass','$first','$last','$major','$birth') ;";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql); header('location: dashboard.php');
 }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="shomare" id="shomare" onblur="check1();" style="margin-left: 5px;width: 200px;">
<br>
<div id="shomare1"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function check1() {
    const shomare = document.getElementById('shomare');
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(shomare.value)) {
        document.getElementById('shomare1').innerHTML = '<a style="font-size: 15px;color: dimgrey;">!کد دانشجویی فقط شامل اعداد می باشد</a>';
        return false;
    }
    if (shomare.value.length != 8) {
        document.getElementById('shomare1').innerHTML = '<a style="font-size: 15px;color: dimgrey;">!کد دانشجویی باید 8 رقمی باشد</a>';
        return false;
    }
    if( /^\d+$/.test(shomare.value) && shomare.value.length == 8 ) {
        document.getElementById('shomare1').innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, it should prevent the submission if your code is correct? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault, Maybe should check if the syntax is correct and you're getting the form event in your event object.

Comment: I suspect that event.preventDefault is not the function you think it is, best to study what that does.

Comment: Preventing the `blur` event's default action won't help. You need to prevent the `submit` of the form, if you don't want to send invalid values.

Comment: To display the error messages, you should listen to either the `change` or the `input` event.